# scipy cephes import error

Tags: python, import, scipy

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to fix this problem.

I recently installed scipy, and I can use most of its modules, except for any that seem to use the `_cephes.so` module in `/scipy/special/`

When I try to import scipy.special I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _cephes import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_cephes.so: undefined symbol: s_stop
```

I have been unable to find anyone else with this error. Notice the undefined symbol is `s_stop` and not `awsfa`.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to the problem? I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Me too.  Ever get any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove scipy and then perform an easy_install of it again. Remove, as far as I know, is somewhat manual, deleting /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy and anything else that looks related.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, I had used some official packages and some from [the collection here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy%20Gohlke%27s%20collection).
After getting this error I noticed this message: *Note: these builds are not completely compatible with the official SciPy binaries.*

So I completely uninstalled scikit-learn, scipy, and numpy, and installed using ONLY packages from that source and it worked.